# What is the [track] tag for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There's a tag on stack-overflow called [track](/questions/tagged/track)

It has no wiki, < 200 questions, and one follower. They appear to be about a variety of topics (music tracks, analytics, miscellaneous recording of actions). The tag is currently (in my opinion) not useful. Some questions probably belong under [analytics](/questions/tagged/analytics), and some probably shouldn't be tagged at all.

I recommend removing the tag.

Comment: `git-track` for those relating to Git, and the rest burninated.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: does the `git-track` tag exist?

Comment: 27 down; 150 to go.  Practically every one needs other editing too, of course, so burninating is hard work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: no, but it would complement `git-commit`, `git-push`, etc.